# Display the user that created an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a small module of thanks by mail. In the list of thanks
I want to show the user who created (send or write) an email, so that in the mailing list it appears who sent it and who wrote it. I am using the devise gem.

this is my code:

controller/gratitudes_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @gratitudes = Gratitude.all
    @gratitude_user = current_user.gratitudes

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @gratitudes }
    end
  end
```

views/gratitudes/index.html:

```
<h1>Listing gratitudes</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Message</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>author</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @gratitudes.each do |gratitude| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= gratitude.subject %></td>
    <td><%= gratitude.message %></td>
    <td><%= gratitude.user.complete_name %></td>
    <td><%= here the author's %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', gratitude %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gratitude_path(gratitude) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', gratitude, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Gratitude', new_gratitude_path %>
```

Comment: correction: who created (send or write) an email(gratitude)

Comment: Can you post the relevant table schema?